# Cleaner way to filter nil in Swift array

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a Swift object called `Animal`. I have an array of `Animal` objects, some of which could be `nil`.

Currently I'm doing this:

`arrayOfAnimal.filter({$0 != nil}) as! [Animal]`

This feels rather hacky because of the force unwrapping. Wondering if there's a better way to filter out nils.

Comment: Your aim is to exclude all the nil values?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`flatMap()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap) does the job:

```
let filtered = arrayOfAnimal.flatMap { $0 }
```

The closure (which is the identity here) is applied to all
elements, and an array with the non-nil results is returned.
The return type is `[Animal]` and no forced cast is needed.

Simple example:

```
let array: [Int?] = [1, nil, 2, nil, 3]
let filtered = array.flatMap { $0 }

print(filtered)            // [1, 2, 3]
print(type(of: filtered))  // Array<Int>
```

For **Swift 4.1** and later, replace `flatMap` by `compactMap`.

Comment: I would use compactMap instead, since flatMap is now depreciated on Swift 4.0.

Answer (score 17):

Your code works, but there is a better way. Use the `compactMap` function.

```
struct Animal {}

let arrayOfAnimal: [Animal?] = [nil, Animal(), Animal(), nil]
let newArray: [Animal] = arrayOfAnimal.compactMap { $0 }
```

Comment: yes, flatMap is deprecated

Comment: This is now the correct answer